# How to consume JSON array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, spring

What i trying to do here is, i want to consume the JSON that i produce using Spring Restful WebService, which is looked like this :

```
[
    {
        "userid": 1,
        "firstName": "kevin",
        "lastName": "buruk",
        "email": "pucuk@ubi.com"
    },
    {
        "userid": 2,
        "firstName": "helm",
        "lastName": "krpuk",
        "email": "helmkrupuk@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "userid": 3,
        "firstName": "batok",
        "lastName": "kelapa",
        "email": "batokkelapa@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

That JSON is produce by this function in my Java Spring MVC Controller, which is looked like this :

SpringController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/")
public class SpringServiceController {

    UserService userService = new UserService();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users=userService.getAllUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

And i am about to consume the JSON value into angular table, so i do store the JSON value in angular object in the scope, here is my Javascript code. i named this file app.js

app.js

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        });
}
```

and here is my html page. i named it index.html
index.html

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Angular Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.userid}}</td>
            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i missed here? i won't show anything. Before this i was trying to consume the JSON that i only have one record, it work properly. But this time i trying to consume the array, and i failed. What i missed here? is it the JSON or my javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to use latest version of angular. Now, it's 1.4.5 with more performance optimizations and features.

About your question: error in html code. Here's the fixed version

```js
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $scope.users = [
    {
        "userid": 1,
        "firstName": "kevin",
        "lastName": "buruk",
        "email": "pucuk@ubi.com"
    },
    {
        "userid": 2,
        "firstName": "helm",
        "lastName": "krpuk",
        "email": "helmkrupuk@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "userid": 3,
        "firstName": "batok",
        "lastName": "kelapa",
        "email": "batokkelapa@gmail.com"
    }
]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="Hello">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.userid}}</td>
            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

As you can see, I fixed it with adding only one html tag!

Comment: oohh! i missed the <table></table> tag. Thank you, but i got another error while i update the angularjs version to 1.4.5

Comment: I think Angular 1.39 stopped supporting sort of free style controllers like this. You need to have a module and add the controller to it.