# Consume rest api angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js AngularJs. I have a remote json in the follwing format

```
{
"abc123":
  {
    "case_desc":"case desc 1",
    "case_img":"abc.jpg"    
  },
  "efg456":
  {
    "case_desc":"case desc 2",
    "case_img":"abc.jpg"
  }
}
```

i want to loop through display the data in the table format with their respective objects

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Here's a link to a previous answer by Axon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622568/how-to-consume-json-array-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to read some documentation and examples about angular. In this case you will need the `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in myObject">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ val.case_desc }}</td>
        <td><img ng-src="val.case_img" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This assumes of course that your data is attached to the scope in your controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.myObject = {
            "abc123": {
                "case_desc":"case desc 1",
                "case_img":"abc.jpg"    
            },
            "efg456": {
                "case_desc":"case_desc 2",
                "case_img":"abc.jpg"
            }
        };
    });
```